# Why do ( within my limited understanding.) Energy and matter act in opposite ways

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, mass-energy, interactions, diffusion

I would like to preface this by stating this type of research is my hobby not my profession.

If I understand the basic explanation correctly, energy tends to spread out evenly within a closed system given enough time and matter tends to clump together due to the fundamental interaction that we refer to as gravity
Based on my very loose understanding of special relativity energy and mass are simply 2 sides of the same coin if this is true, then why does energy not clump together as mass does or vis versa?

Comment: What phenomena are you thinking of, specifically, when you say "energy tends to spread out evenly"?

Comment: I see your point. Hot matter tends to follow diffusion as well. It's not really based on "energy density" ( I think I used that term correctly.) I'm an electrician so I tend to think of energy as electrical energy which wants to spread out and become neutral. While the matter in the system remains more or less in the same place with minimal physical changes.

Comment: “energy tends to spread out evenly within a closed system given enough time“ sounds to me like heat spreading out  (so an entropy type thought). Hence thermo tag, i suppose

Comment: @JohnA. That is the idea that I was basing my assumption on. I suppose I may have made a leap in logic to assume that all forms of energy would have similar systems.

Comment: I should note that my original comment (which @TylerTheSparky replied to but which I deleted because I figured I should ask for clarification instead) is that I think this is really a question about why cold things clump while while hot things disperse. (And that this behavior isn't specific to gravitational systems!)

Comment: @Sten Thank you. I kept trying to find it to see if I had addressed it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Energy and matter are unified in the special theory in the sense that instead of thinking about energy and momentum (motion of matter) separately as in the Newtonian paradigm; one instead thinks in terms of energy-momentum as one mathematically fundamental entity. Energy-momentum within the special theory can be quantified as a *four vector*, the square magnitude of which is given by the, perhaps familiar to you, relation:
$$m^2c^4=E^2-p^2c^2.$$
One must be careful, however, not to carry the concept of matter-energy unification so far as to think that matter and energy should also be unified in the way in which they interact in the universe. For example, although matter is attracted to matter through the force of gravity, gravity is not the only way through which matter interacts. Charged matter, as you know, can be attractive, however; it can also be repulsive, i.e. two conductive spheres with like charge push each other away. An example from chemistry can be found in the immiscibility of oil and water; Additionally, ionic compounds like sodium chloride have chemical bonds which are electrostatic in nature and represent a kind of material attraction far stronger than the gravitational.
Energy does indeed often have the "spreading" character you spoke of, e.g. heat has a diffusive nature (matter-based viruses migrating through air do too), however, light can be found behaving in ways that make it rather energy-like (interference); as well as rather matter-like (photo-electric effect). Further still, quarks represent a kind of matter interacting via the strong force; the way in which matter interacts is more due to the intrinsic property of the type of fundamental force that dominates the particulars of the specific interaction in question. Exactly how this works for gravity is not yet fully understood as no one has figured out how to unify Einstein's gravity with the other four fundamental forces.
In short, matter and energy behave in sometimes disparate ways despite their unified treatment within the Special theory of relativity.